# Can't release to AppStore with Delphi 10 Seattle and iOS 9

Tags: xcode, delphi, xcode7, delphi-10-seattle

I am using *XCode 7* and *Delphi 10 Seattle*.

If I try to deploy to *AppStore* I got these messages.

> **ERROR ITMS-90507**: "Missing Info.plist valua. A value for the kay DTPlatformName in bundle .. is required."
>
> **ERROR ITMS-90094**: "Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with iOS 6.0 SDK or later."
>
> **ERROR ITMS-90534**: "Invalid Toochain. News and app updates must be built with the public (GM) version of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or ...

Comment: Did you try to open an old project or did you create a new one? If former, does it work with a newly created project?

Answer (score 2):

***ERROR ITMS-90507:***

To resolve this issue the `DTPlatformName` key must be added to the project's plist file with the correct value. The easiest way is to add it under **"Project->Options->Version Info"** with the `"iOS 64 bits - Release"` configuration set. On the "Key/Value list box" right-click anywhere in the list of fields and select "Add Key". Put `"DTPlatformName"` as key and `"iphoneos"` as value.

[image]
[image]

***ERROR ITMS-90094***

Try setting the iOS Device 64 bit->Configuration to `'application store'` in the project manager.

***ERROR ITMS-90534***

I had the same problem, turns out that one of my libraries installed via bower includes a `.sh` file, which is not needed. I have just deleted the file and everything has been uploaded successfully.

Seems like that Apple now enforces developers to have `.sh` files in their apps signed. As Cordova/Phonegap app don't need any of them, you can safely delete them.